# Intel Team TCP Offloading not Working

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2, intel

I verified that TCP offloading is enabled in both the Intel properties for each of NIC that is the member of a two nic Adapter Fault Tolerance Team.

Also, the output of `netsh int tcp show global` verified that offloading is enabled.

However, when running `netstat -tn` none of the connections are offloaded, they are all `InHost`. Has anyone seen this problem before? Are adapter fault tolerant teams not compatible with offloading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"TOE (TCP Offload Engine) enabled devices can not be added to an ANS team and will not appear in the list of available adapters. If a TOE enabled device is added to an ANS team, it will not be able to do connection offloading while it is a member of the team."

Does this apply? http://public.support.unisys.com/pcproducts/esx/docs/DellDocs5.4/en/IntelNIC/usage.htm#adapter_teaming

Comment: Intel says something similar as well: "TOE (TCP Offload Engine) enabled devices cannot be added to a team and will not appear in the list of available adapters." However, it says that after "Some advanced features, including hardware offloading, are automatically disabled when non-Intel adapters are team members to assure a common feature set." Which seems strange thing to say if Offloading is not supported in 100% Intel teams as well. So does this mean that Intel Teams just don't support offloading?

Comment: "So does this mean that Intel Teams just don't support offloading?" That's how I'm taking it, but I can't speak from experience on this point, just from poorly worded documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You're out of luck dude;

["TOE (TCP Offload Engine) enabled devices cannot be added to a team and will not appear in the list of available adapters."](http://www.intel.com/support/network/sb/cs-009747.htm)

I do understand why not though to be honest, it's a lot to ask in a way.

Comment: See comments on pk's answer -- it doesn't really make since to say that after offloading is not supported if one of the adapters is not Intel.